# AWS codebuild issue with assuming role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, sts

Newbie here, when trying to deploy I get the following error in codebuild:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeRepositories operation: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/foo-staging-application-deploy/codebuild-kubectl is not authorized to perform: ecr:DescribeRepositories on resource: arn:aws:ecr:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:repository/app-main because no resource-based policy allows the ecr:DescribeRepositories action
```

foo-staging-application-deploy has all the access needed, do anyone know what the issue might be? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the policy of the user and the role it is assuming? Clearly it doesn't have the access you think it does.

Comment: Thanks for answering Lawrence, I solved the issue at the end, it was the ECR repository permissions, it was in another account so I simply gave permissions